# Searching R corpus for all words ending in "esque"

Tags: regex, r, dictionary, text-mining, tm

I am using R's `tm` package to get word frequencies using the dictionary method. I want to find all words that end with "esque" whether they are spelled "abcd-esque", "abcdesque" or "abcd esque" (since all different spellings exist in my corpus). How can I create a regular expression for this? This is what I have so far. Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
text <- Corpus(DirSource("txt/"))
text <- tm_map(text,tolower) 
text <- tm_map(text,stripWhitespace) 
dtm.text <- DocumentTermMatrix(text)
list<-inspect(
    DocumentTermMatrix(text,list(dictionary = c("rose", "green", "esque")))
)
```

Comment: `grep("esque$",x)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
inspect(dtm.text[, grepl("esque$", dtm.text$dimnames$Terms)])
```

As a side note `tolower` won't work with a current version of `tm`. You should use `contetn_transformer` instead:

```
tm_map(text, content_transformer(tolower))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
words = c("rose", "green", "esque", "abcd-esque", "abcdesque", "abcd esque")
grep("esque$", words)
```